# Is there a Gmail notifier that integrates with the Messaging menu?

Tags: 11.04, unity, gmail, messaging-menu

how can i get it back in natty 11.04? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer [GmailWatcher](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/gmailwatcher-gmail-notifier-especially.html) which neatly integrates with the other notifications in Unity/Gnome.

Comment: nice! that's what i'm looking for.

Comment: I can't make it to work in unity, annoying.

Comment: Didn't work well for me, and was buggy. However, Cloud Service Notifications worked really well (installed from git).

Answer (score 8):

Try installing the `gm-notify` package, this will give you :

- notifications on new mail,
- integration with the messaging indicator.

Comment: It doesn't seem to support multiple accounts.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [Cloud Service Notifications](http://chuchiperriman.github.com/cloud-services-notifications) and it works great. In addition to gmail notifications you can also set up notifications for google reader, pop3, twitter, rss and others.

Comment: thanks mate. this is great app, but i need it in the messaging menu.

Comment: You can choose whether you want it in the messaging menu or as a status icon in the settings.

Comment: I just installed from git, and it is a great simple and versatile solution.

Answer (score 2):

Also, [Popper](https://launchpad.net/popper) integrates nicely into message indicator for any email provider

Comment: After reading through this thread and trying a few of the suggested notifiers, I am sticking with Popper for now. It's versatile, integrates well with the Natty indicator and it has a good configuration tool with helpful tooltips and a well-written help file. I don't like desktop mail clients for Gmail (too slow), which is why I also liked the fact that the commands invoked on clicking on a new mail header are configurable. I deferred all actions to Firefox opening Gmail in the right places (with some help from http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments)