# Unity mail applet

Tags: 11.04, unity, panel, applet, email

I'm new here and started using Unity just 4 days ago. I have used Docky and AWN before. I mean i don't need all that neat stuff, but just the mail applet. Just to be in touch with mail.

Is there any way to be do this in with the Unity panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pin the evolution application to the Unity Launcher. It has nice integration with Ubuntu. It is also the default application, so you don't have to go through the hassle of installing it. Just search for "mail" in the dash and then pin it to your launcher.

Comment: this is a solution i suppose, thank you
but i was looking for something small and something like those applets for awn or docky

Comment: Can you clarify which "mail"?  If it Gmail then try the suggestions here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/37894/is-there-a-gmail-notifier-that-integrates-with-the-messaging-menu

Comment: yes, gmail. i thought about unity panel, but this will do

Comment: @fossfreedom In the link you provided, the application popper can handle any mail account not just Gmail...but yeah good suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Try Unity Mail:

https://launchpad.net/unity-mail

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/unity-mail-displays-gmail-unread-count.html

Comment: Thanks!  I was looking for a way to add something like this to the Unity launcher. I'd rather store my passwords in the Gnome Keyring instead of a plain text config file, but hey, it at least it works!

Comment: After a recent update, the application no longer stores the passwords in plain text!