# Gmail notification on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: gmail, messaging-menu

I'm upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10 and then to 13.04. In 12.04 I was usage with `gm-notify` to alert me when a message is coming in the messaging menu. In 13.04 its not shown in the messaging menu.

There is another sample app that show in the messaging menu when message is coming to Gmail?

Comment: Possible duplicate. It's old, but some answers might still be relevant. http://askubuntu.com/questions/37894/is-there-a-gmail-notifier-that-integrates-with-the-messaging-menu?rq=1

Comment: I saw that, and I tested it, and it does not meet my requirements.
GmailWatcher - no messages appear on the menu.
  Cloud Service Notifications-not open at all ...
  Popper-'ve opened a bug in https://bugs.launchpad.net/popper/+bug/1070308

Answer (score 6):

For me, Unity Mail resolved the issue.

`apt-get install unity-mail` or install it from *Ubuntu Software Center* searching for **Unity Mail**.

Answer (score -2):

If you have either Firefox or Chromium installed then you can use the Web App.

Click here: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-webapps-gmail/

and install the Web App.

Comment: I've had it installed, but it's not really comfortable, and it does not appear on the menu messages